# accessing browser history via javascript to implement custom back and forward buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have custom back and forward buttons on my page.

The back button should be enabled only if the history.back page is from my website.

Similary the forward button should be enabled only if the history.forward page belongs to my website.

document.referrer returns the name of the previous page.

How do I get the name of the forward page?

Answer (score 1):

See here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_history.asp. There's is no standard way of doing what you're trying to achieve.

One suggestion would be to implement you're own history chain...

For each link followed (excluding back and forward) you add an item to the back-stack and clear the forward stack.

On clicking back, you pop from the back-stack to get your url. You push this item to the forward-stack.

On clicking forward, you pop from the forward-stack to get your url. You push this item to the back-stack.

A different approach may be to use breadcrumb navigation rather than history navigation. This requires a more structured site.

Comment: Could you please help me by providing some links on how to achieve this. I have no idea how to achieve this functionality. On IE8+ browsers I could use sessionStorage, however my application has to run on IE7 as well. sessionStorage is not supported on IE7.